# Creating handle feature for my drag and drop plugin bugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, handle

I'm creating a drag and drop plugin and trying to get the handler feature to work...

I'm trying this code:

```
  $(o.handle).mousedown(function(event) {
        down = true;
        var dx = event.pageX - $(this).position().left,
        dy = event.pageY - $(this).position().top;
        $(oj).css({
            cursor: 'move',
        }).mousemove(function(event) {
            if (down == true) {
                $(oj).css({
                    cursor: 'move',
                    left: event.pageX - dx,
                    top: event.pageY - dy + 110
                });
            }
        });
```

`o.handle` is the ID of the handler
`oj` is referring to `this`

The Problem is that once you click the handler it moves the element its suppose to drag, but, then once you try to drag it again it goes all haywire. As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/GMaZR/). I don't know why it works the first time thought. But not any other time.